# Rewrite this regex without using lookbehind - invalid regex with JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

Only minimal experience with Regex, I am trying to implement some email masking in node.js, all was well running it locally but once pushed up to the server I am getting invalid Regex errors.

The Regex code example can be found here

https://regexr.com/42uid

```
var email = 'foo@bar.com'
const regex = /(.)[^@\n](?=[^@\n]*[^@\n]@)|(?:(@.)|(?!^)\G(?=[^@]*$)).(?!$)/g;
const maskedEmail = email.replace(regex, '*');
```

maskedEmail should return

```
  f*o@b*r.com
```

I have narrowed the issue down to being the 'lookbehind/lookahead' which as I understand it is not available in JS. However I am not aware how best to re-write it.

Comment: corrected link :    https://regexr.com/42uid

Comment: `\G` is not supported in Javascript / node.js unless you are just trying to match literal `G`

Comment: What is the rule to replace a char with an asterisk? Could you give more examples? For example, what is the expected result for: `thisismyemail@myserver.mytld`

Comment: ignoring the first and last character of the address before @ , replace all characters with an *.  ignoring first and last character of the text between @ and . replace characters with * . However  I have simplified my requirements  significantly in the solution I have implemented now and used :        /\B.[^@]*\B/i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture it in multiple groups and then retrieve that data in the replace with `$1`, `$2`, etc.

By using this regex: `^(.).*(.@.).*(.\.[^\.]+)$`
and using the following replace string: `$1*$2*$3`
it will result in: `f*o@b*r.com`

Link to my Fiddle: https://regexr.com/42um8

Comment: thanks I will have a play around with this. I read about capture groups but didnt quite understand them, your example makes it very clear now.